# List of immiscible liquids

Tags: physical-chemistry

I'm looking for a list of immiscible (and miscible) liquids.

I currently developing a game that will use the property of differents liquid, some of them will mix, other will not (positioning in the recipient is important so density is).

I'm searching but not found anything very relevant.

Of course I know water, oil (and mercury). But I'm looking for more than two (at least 8 differents elements in three or four groups).

I can always invent them but I'd like to keep things real as far as I can.

The elements must be at the liquid state in normal conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "common" chart in most chemistry labs that covers exactly this topic. One version of it can be found here: http://chemistry.kenyon.edu/getzler/Research%20files/miscibility_elutropicity.pdf

For reference's sake, this was found by a Google Image search using the term "miscibility." A clear case of having to know something exists in order to find it.

Comment: thanks that was exactly what i've been looking for , even if some of them are not really know by everyone.

Comment: A damn fine chart.  I wonder about the significance of **water** having the most immiscible marks.  Does that reveal some fundamental nature of water and it's utility for life?  Or is that anthropomorphically just the kind of table that would be devised by a water-based organism?

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5503/what-exactly-is-hydrogen-bonding-and-why-cant-it-exist-with-atoms-other-than-f